# incorrect rounding in php 7.1

Tags: php, php-7.1

```
1.15 * 100              // 115 correct
(int)(1.15 * 100)       // 114 incorrect
intval(1.15 * 100)      // 114 incorrect

floor(1.15 * 100)       // 114 incorrect
floor(1.1501 * 100)     // 115 correct
```

I try to cut off the fractional part after the 2nd character and translate it into an integer. It turns out with an error. Tell me how to correctly translate.

Comment: The result is the same in version `7.1.1`, `5.4.36` and `5.6.2`.

Comment: This isn't a php 7 question, yet alone 7.1. RTM's http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: As mentioned in `intval()` function documentation's comment, you can first use `strval()`, then use `intval()`, e.g. `intval(strval(1.15 * 100))` which gives you correct results.

Comment: you could also use the number_format function with zero decimals `(int)number_format((1.15 * 100),0)` or cast it first into a string `(int)(string)(1.15 * 100)`

Comment: @Raptor You beat me to posting my answer. I added your single line as an alternative.

Comment: `1.15` can't be represented exactly in floating point, it's actually something like `1.1499999999999923`. That's why you get the result you see. Use `round()` instead of `floor()` to mitigate problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_dump( 1.15 * 100 );` outputs a float - unmodified.

`var_dump( (int)(1.15 * 100) );` outputs an int - the float above converted to an int, which does rounding even for seemingly the same number.

```
$var1 = (string)(1.15 * 100);
var_dump( (int)($var1) );
```

You would need to convert the float to a string first, then to an int.

Edit: Or a single line answer: `intval(strval(1.15 * 100))`